# Copy files from FTP to blob storage

Tags: azure-logic-apps

There is a lot of posts around copying files from ftp to blob. But all uses a trigger that is named "When a files is added or modifed". I dont have that trigger. I only have the "When a file is added or modfied - properties only". Is this a license thing or am I doing something wrong. Anyone has a similar example for my option?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `When a file is added or modified` has been **DEPRECATED**, you could check it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/ftpconnector/#when-a-file-is-added-or-modified-[deprecated]). For now the FTP trigger only supports `When a file is added or modified (properties only)`.

So if you want to use this trigger to copy file to blob, you could use the FTP action `Get file content using path` with the dynamic content from the trigger, then copy the file content to blob. The below is my test, you could refer to it.

[image]

And here is the run history.

[image]

Further more information about FTP connector, you could refer to this site:[FTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/ftp/). Hope this could help you, if you still have other problem, please feel free to let me know.